# Need to get email alerts of Announcements in Rich Text

Tags: wss-3.0

I want to email alerts sent when new Announcements are made to be in Rich Text format.

Is it possible?

What files are required to be modified?

Pls help!

-saumil

ps i use WSS 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alert templates are stored in \TEMPLATE\XML\Alerttemplates.xml in your SharePoint root (aka 12 hive). This file is used to create alert messages from each list type in WSS 3.0. You can customize these alerts by modifying a copy of Alerttemplates.xml (not the original file) and then loading the customized alert templates using [stsadm](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-2007-products-and-technologies/dd278299%28v=office.12%29):

```
stsadm -o updatealerttemplates -filename myalerttemplates.xml -url http://mysite/
```

More information can be found on [TechNet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sharepointdeveloperdocs/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0).